# warning: refname 'HEAD' is ambiguous

Tags: git

I am new to Git and I seem to have one branch too many if I execute the following command:

```
warning: refname 'HEAD' is ambiguous.
```

I get the following output:

```
warning: refname 'HEAD' is ambiguous.
From github.com:dagda1/hornget
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
warning: refname 'HEAD' is ambiguous.
warning: refname 'HEAD' is ambiguous.
```

If I execute `git branch -a`

I get the following:

```
HEAD
* master
remotes/emmekappa/master
remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
remotes/origin/master
```

I am confused by the `remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master`.

What is this and how can I get rid of the ambiguous branch.

I got to this stage by performing a merge where I think I added the ambiguous branch.

Comment: What is the first command you try to execute? Surely it is not `warning: refname 'HEAD' is ambiguous.`

Comment: `remotes/origin/HEAD  -> origin/master` is not a problem: it just shows which branch is default in remote `origin`.  The branch named **`HEAD`** is.

Comment: I think you need to edit the question to show the command you where trying to execute :)

Comment: To reproduce this, run "git fetch origin HEAD:HEAD". Apparently it tries to merge the current branch into a new branch called, literally, HEAD.

Answer (score 256, accepted):

The problem is that you have a branch called `HEAD` which is absolutely dangerous, since that's the symbolic name for whatever branch is the *current* branch.

Rename it:

```
git branch -m HEAD newbranch
```

then you can examine it and decide what to do (delete it, or save under a descriptive branch name)

(The `origin/HEAD` remote branch is not a problem)

Comment: This can also happen if you happen to have a file or directory with the same name as a branch.

Comment: While `origin/HEAD` might not be a problem, if you accidentally create a branch called `origin/somebranch` that IS a problem (and will result in the same "ambiguous" error message).  When you try to pull from "somebranch", you'll wind up pulling from your local (accidental) branch rather than the remote.  In that case, I found that flickerfly's suggestion of doing `git branch -d origin/somebranch` works great.

Comment: That fixed it, thanks. Worth to note, the "HEAD" branch is created automatically, not by me. It contained a single merge commit and I failed to revert to a clean state using reflog. So, I renamed the branch, deleted it, rebased my "1 ahead" local master to the origin/master, pushed without a problem

Comment: The same can happen for tags, not only branches.

Comment: I restarted the App I was using and no luck. In desperation, I turned my computer off and back on and all is fine. I'm going to the pub, this shit is crazy.

Comment: hah! i work with robots which have a head and had created a branch named `head` (lowercase).

Comment: For me, a series of mistakes produced a tag `HEAd`, which produced this problem from `git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD`.  The match here is definitely case-insensitive.

Comment: I don't have a 'head' branch on my local system. I still get the same ambiguous warning. Why would that be?

Comment: @mantri - check tags if they contains "head" 
```git tag | grep -i head```

Comment: I get the same error but don't have branch HEAD local nor remote

Comment: Use `git show-ref` or `git for-each-ref` to dump all refs. Also, look in the Git directory (`ls .git` or similar) to see if there's some stray file that got created that should not exist - I had this happen once, and I still don't know what created the file. (This was a different case, where I got an ambiguous name `master` warning.)

Answer (score 42):

If you have created a tag named `HEAD` using...

```
git tag HEAD
```

...you can just delete that tag using:

```
git tag -d HEAD
```

See this case: [kerneltrap.org/git-tag HEAD](http://kerneltrap.org/mailarchive/git/2008/2/5/723304)

Comment: This happens when you add tag with name HEAD by mistake, so you have to delete it as suggested here

Comment: solves my problem! there's no branch named HEAD in my repo, don't know how is this tag created..

Answer (score 41):

Also, this will delete the branch, if you just don't want it.

```
git branch -d HEAD
```

Use a capital `-D` to force the deletion:

```
git branch -D HEAD
```

Comment: but it will still remain ambigous, is there a way to purge it ?

Answer (score 5):

Check references available in your git repository. You will observe two HEAD in your repository. This makes your branch with refname HEAD ambiguous.

```
git show-ref
```

Solution:

- Rename the branch

  ```
  git branch -m HEAD <new_branch_name>
  ```

  OR
- Delete the branch

  ```
  git branch -d HEAD
  ```

Answer (score 4):

This means that you have a branch named "head". I had the same issue, I solved by doing the following command.

```
git branch -d head
```