# git merge upstream/master "already up-to-date"

Tags: git, github

Just a disclaimer: After a few months of working with git, I still have literally no idea what I'm doing when I use it. The only time things work is when I exactly follow the instructions I find on the web on various pages.

What I'm trying to do is update my repository, which is forked from another project. I found that these instructions work and I have been following them every time I want to update

However, this time when I try to merge I get this:

```bash
warning: refname 'upstream/master' is ambiguous.
Already up-to-date
```

And nothing happens, even though the project from which I forked has made recent commits. I don't really know what went wrong, and I'm really frustrated. Sorry if this question is incredibly noobish and/or stupid.

**EDIT 1:** Also, I have searched for numerous solutions with no success.

**EDIT 2:** output of git branch -a

```bash
* master
upstream/master
remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
remotes/origin/log-upgrade
remotes/origin/master
remotes/origin/past-gens
remotes/origin/prototype-party
remotes/upstream/log-upgrade
remotes/upstream/master
remotes/upstream/past-gens
remotes/upstream/prototype-party
```

**EDIT 3:** Similar questions

[git refname 'origin/master' is ambiguous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26046698/git-refname-origin-master-is-ambiguous)
[Git: refname 'master' is ambiguous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12224773/git-refname-master-is-ambiguous)
[warning: refname 'HEAD' is ambiguous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1692892/warning-refname-head-is-ambiguous)
[Git warning: refname 'xxx' is ambiguous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28192422/git-warning-refname-xxx-is-ambiguous)

Comment: Could you add the output of `git branch -a`? If you're unsure what you're doing with `git`, I'd recommend a read of [the Pro Git book](http://git-scm.com/book), which I found really helpful when learning the theory behind `git`. Has nice diagrams and everything.

Answer (score 8):

You've got two branches called `upstream/master`. One is a local branch, and one is the branch on the remote. When you try to do a `git merge`, `git` doesn't know which of these two branches you wish to merge from, hence the ambiguity.

This can be seen from the `git branch -a` (show all `git` branches, including remotes):

```
upstream/master
<SNIP>
remotes/upstream/master
```

To fix this, you could either rename (or delete) the *local* branch:

```
git branch -m <old name> <new name>
```

In your case, you'd rename something like this (change name to `newname`):

```
git branch -m upstream/master newname
```

This should allow you to do a `git fetch` / `git merge` properly.

Comment: I renamed upstream/master to upstream/mastertwo, but now when I try to merge from upstream/mastertwo it still says up-to-date.

Comment: You renamed the _local_ branch, which is _probably_ unnecessary and was created just as a result of some mistake in your use of git. You want to merge from the _remote_ branch that should be still named upstream/master.

Answer (score 2):

Either just run:

```
git merge remotes/upstream/master
```

instead of

```
git merge upstream/master
```

or delete your local `upstream/master` branch, by running:

```
git branch -d upstream/master
```

And learn how git works ;). It’s not that complicated and once you understood the core principles everything is quite easy.