# How to fix "Nothing to show" on WebStorm > Version Control view > log tab

Tags: git, webstorm

Steps:

1. After doing some `git rebase` operations  and deleting a branch with `git branch -D`
2. On Version Control view, log tab, no data is shown
3. Pressing  Refresh will quickly show the log data, then it goes back to "Nothing to show", and no Git log data is shown

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-20024

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The message *"warning: refname 'HEAD' is ambiguous."* was shown on the Console, so the fix was [renaming the ambiguous local HEAD branch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1692926/1159167) with `git branch -m HEAD HEAD_TMP`

Comment: I'm not sure how the HEAD branch was added, though!