# Git Modification Check Failed Error in Thoughtworks Go.CD

Tags: git, go-cd, thoughtworks-go

I am getting the following error in Thoughtworks Go for one of the projects, what does it mean and how can I fix it?

> Modification check failed for material: URL:
>   https://username:******@bitbucket.org/company/project.git,
>   Branch: [Mar-03 17:08:55] Error performing command: --- Command ---
>   git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD --- Environment --- {} --- INPUT ----
>   --OUTPUT --- HEAD --- ERROR --- STDERR: fatal: ambiguous argument 'HEAD': unknown revision or path not in the working tree. STDERR: Use
>   '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this: STDERR: 'git [...]
>   -- [...]' ---

Comment: Make sure you don't have a branch named `HEAD`. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1692892/warning-refname-head-is-ambiguous

Comment: @Jonathan.Brink That did not seem to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the pipeline XML, there was one where the material had set the branch to be an empty string like so: `branch=""`. Once I deleted this, the error went away.