# warning: refname 'HEAD' is ambiguous - but no HEAD branch

Tags: git, tags, ambiguity, git-refspec

I've been generating a few git repositories from CVS repositories using the [crap](https://github.com/rcls/crap/) tool (it's not crap!...)

Unfortunately, with one of them, and after the export, I keep getting complaints about HEAD being an ambiguous reference. I've read:

[warning: refname 'HEAD' is ambiguous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1692892/warning-refname-head-is-ambiguous)

but unlike in that case - I don't have a branch named HEAD. So, what's the cause of this ambiguity?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's not a branch, it could be a tag. Check this with:

```
git --no-pager tag -l HEAD
```

if it produces an output line with `HEAD` on it, then - that's your problem. Now, you can either:

1. Rename the tag (difficult - since the instructions in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1028649/1593077) won't work due to the ambiguity), or
2. Delete the tag, like so:

   ```
   git tag -d HEAD
   ```

   (See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2003505/1593077) on deleting tags.)